# Mathematica: Operations on list with missing values

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, operations

I try and perform operations on a set of lists.  For example:
Lists:
(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5),
(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
(1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5)

Then I would like for example to have a list containing the means.
Mean[lists] doesnt run properly because it does not know how to handle the missing values "NA".
What I expect is:
(1, 1, 5/3, 7/3, 3, 4, 4, etc.)

Does anybody how to ignore the missing or 'text' values? Like you would operate such a function in excel for example.
Thanks!

Comment: Could possibly find more help here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're interested in the mean of the columns of the matrix. If your data array is rectangular you could do something like this

```
lst = {{1, 1, 1, "NA", "NA"}, {2, 3, 4, 5, "NA"}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};
Mean /@ DeleteCases[Transpose[lst], a_ /; Not[NumericQ[a]], {-1}]
```

A simpler method would be to replace whatever symbol is used for non-available elements (for example `"NA"` in `lst`) by `Sequence[]`:

```
Mean /@ (Transpose[lst] /. "NA" -> Sequence[])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = {{1, 1, 1, "NA", "NA"}, {2, 3, 4, 5, "NA"}}
Mean@# & /@ (Cases[#, Except@"NA"] & /@ l)

(*
-> {1, 7/2}
*)
```

Comment: Also `Mean /@ (Cases[#, Except@"NA"] & /@ l)`